# Why do $n-1$ lines connect $n$ dots, when the lines share dots?

Tags: geometry

If you take n dots (or vertices) and connect them together with lines, you'll have n−1 lines. But why n−1? Please assist me with this triviality.  Other than the obvious visual proof, can you prove this more rigorously?

If there's n dots, only the first line requires two unique dots and every subsequent one requires only 1 additional dot. But I still don't see the $n-1$ in that.

Let ⬤ be a dot.

Then ⬤ ------------------------ ⬤ ------------------------ ⬤
denotes 3 dots, 2 lines.

In general, $n$ dots are separated by $n-1$ lines.

For example, I can easily see how $n$ disconnected dots give $n/2$ lines, because there must be $m$ groups of 2 dots or $m$ lines.

Comment: Can you explain more about what exactly you are talking about? *I* can't tell.

Comment: If you take $n$ vertices and connect them together with lines, you'll have $n-1$ lines, why $n-1$? Other than the obvious visual proof, is there something that could be more, I don't know, substantial?

Comment: Explain that in *the body of the question*, so that people do not have to read through all comments.

Comment: @NKLost You'll also have to be more clear about how you are connecting the dots. In my mind, connecting 3 dots yields three lines, and 4 dots yield 6 lines. I also see ways in which 234987 dots yield one line.

Comment: @NKLost That said, once you sufficiently rigorize the question, induction will work.

Comment: Dot, then line, dot, then line, ..., dot, then line, dot.  There's one more dot than line.  Isn't that enough of a proof?

Comment: (A remark from @Pete Clark's [notes on induction](http://math.uga.edu/~pete/3200induction.pdf).) Some scholars have suggested that what is essentially an argument by mathematical induction appears in the later middle Platonic dialogue Parmenides, lines 149a7-c3. But this argument is of mostly historical and philosophical interest. The statement in question is, very roughly, that if $n$ objects are placed adjacent to another in a linear fashion, the number of points of contact between them is $n − 1$. [contd]

Comment: [contd] (Maybe. To quote the lead in the wikipedia article on the Parmenides: "It is widely considered to be one of the more, if not the most, challenging and enigmatic of Plato’s dialogues.") There is not much mathematics here! Nevertheless, for a thorough discussion of induction in the Parmenides the reader may consult [Ac00] and the references cited therein.

Comment: Ultimately it doesn't have to be "in a linear fashion" - this generalizes to [finite] trees. (basically, you get to attach the "then line, dot" anywhere instead of at the dot you added most recently)

Answer (score 4):

If you are in $1$ town and you want to visit $n$ towns, then you have to walk *to* $n-1$ towns.

Answer (score 4):

See [Fencepost Error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fencepost_error#Fencepost_error).  This is really just a matter of counting carefully, and of having a precise understanding of what you are counting.

Here's what I think you mean: You have $n$ vertices $v_1, v_2, v_3, \ldots, v_n$, and you want to count the line segments connecting ($v_1$ and $v_2$), ($v_2$ and $v_3$), $\ldots$, all the way to ($v_{n-1}$ and $v_n$).

We can label each line segment by taking the smaller of the indices of the two vertices $v_i$ and $v_j$ it connects.  Then we have $n-1$ line segments, $\ell_1, \ell_2, \ldots, \ell_{n-1}$.

Notice that if we connected the vertices in a loop, we would have one more line segment, connecting ($v_n$ and $v_1$), to make $n$ total line segments.  If we have a single chain (not a loop) with $n$ *interior* vertices, then we have $n+1$ line segments. (That is, we add vertices $v_0$ on one end and $v_{n+1}$ on the other end, making $n+2$ vertices total, but only $n$ *interior* vertices.)

In counting problems like this, you have to think carefully about the correct way to count.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of counting lines, how about counting *left ends of lines*? Every dot except the last one is adjacent to exactly one left end, and the last one is adjacent to none.

There are $n-1$ dots-except-the-last-one (which is just how subtraction works, nothing to prove there), so that is also the number of left ends, and therefore also the number of lines.