# Suppose a whole number is selected at random between 100 and 999 inclusive.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

(a) How many outcomes are in Ω?

(b) What is the probability the selected number has at least one 1 in it?

(c) What is the probability the selected number has exactly two 3’s in it?

What I have so far:

a). Sample Space = 999-100-899

b). No. of one's between 200-999 = 8 rows *10 + 8 times 10(201, 211, 212,.. 301,311,..991) + 8 times 8(for the extra 1's like 211, 311..911)  = 704
    No. of one's between 100-190 = # of one's  between 100-119 +(120-190)
                                 = 11+17 + (8*10 + (8))
                                 = 28 + 88 = 116

Total no.of one's in it = 116 + 704 = 820
probability of getting atleast one 1 in it = 820/ 899

So, I don't think I'm approaching the problem right at all. My answer looks very wrong. Can someone help me to come on the right track?

I have no idea on how to do the third part with a different strategy than I have used so far. Any help would be much appreciated!!!

Comment: a is wrong. should be $999-100+1=900$.

Comment: Less chocolate. More math.

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: @ChocolateAndMath  You have a [fencepost error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error#Fencepost_error)

Comment: Googling what a fencepost error is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How many outcomes are in $\Omega$?

$999-100+1=900$

> What is the probability that the selected number has at least $1$ "1" in it?

$(900-8\cdot9\cdot9)/900=28\%$

> What is the probability that the selected number has exactly $2$ "3"’s in it?

$(1\cdot1\cdot9+1\cdot9\cdot1+8\cdot1\cdot1)/900=2.\overline{8}\%$

Comment: Why are we adding 1?

Comment: @ChocolateAndMath: The analogy is "$1$ rope has $2$ ends". Try it with a smaller range, and you'll understand. For example, how many values are $\in[0,5]$?

Comment: @ChocolateAndMath: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/879706/131263), and you'll find a few more ways to explain why we need to add $1$.

Comment: Right. So, it is like indexing in for loops. So, it is including 0? So, in the first part I calulcated from 101-999 and not 100-999? (1-9 in place of 0-9?)

Comment: @ChocolateAndMath: Or from $100$ to $998$.

Comment: okay! got it. Can you explain how you got the second part?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52377/discussion-between-chocolateandmath-and-barak-manos).

Answer (score 1):

For b you shouldn't count the number of ones because you will double count numbers like $112$ that have two of them.  Once you have the correct answer for a it is easiest to count and subtract the numbers that do not have $1$s.  How many choices for the hundreds digit if $1$ is prohibited?  The other digits?  How many numbers have no $1$s?

For c, how many ways to select which two digits are $3$?  How many ways to select the third digit?